# Modifying coreboot settings on windows

Tags: windows, bios

I am on a machine (modified Chromebook) running coreboot with windows on it, i want to access the BIOS or a setting file to maybe enable virtualization, the problem is that if i try to access the bios no matter what it takes me to the boot menu.

If it is possible to modify BIOS setting please help me but if it's not i could get a Linux live USB if it helps.

CPU-Z report = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fs8Bm09vbPobwLncTY99HS1HP4e3Um75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First of all.. knowing that there is no BIOS anymore might help your search.  People still use the term as if they are the same but they are not.  You have UEFI firmware through coreboot, not a BIOS.  Have you tried getting to it from Windows?  "How to access UEFI windows" in google will take you to how to do it.. one quick way... restart windows but hold down shift when you click on restart.

Comment: Thanks, I will try